# android upload image not working in facebook messenger SDK webview

Tags: android, reactjs, facebook, webview, upload

I'm developing a facebook chatbot that sends template message to users.
The template uses facebook messenger SDK and opens a webview of my react app website, and the website has `<input type="file" />` in it.

When I clicked the `Choose File` button and then select an image file, the input didn't show the selected file and the `onChange` event was not called.

```
<input
  onChange={handleOnChange}
  type="file"
  accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg, image/gif"
  capture={false}
/>
```

The problem only happens in some of android phones. :(

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when opening my website from messenger app.
What happened is that the event is getting lost with the rendering of your component.
To solve it I used **e.persist()** to save the event data. My callback is also **async**:

```
const handleOnChange = async e => {
  e.persist();
  /*Rest of the logic */
};

<input
  onChange={handleOnChange}
  type="file"
  accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg, image/gif"
  capture={false}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me, cannot believe that it only happened on some Android browser. In my case it is VueJS.

```html
      input(
        ref="file",
        type="file",
        accept="image/*",
        @change="select($event)"
      )
```